# empty response return from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, express

I am trying to fetch some data from my server and when testing the request with Postman it works great and I getting data back. But then when I trying to implement the request in my app Im getting back an empty object with `undefined` properties

CODE:

```
fetchUserData = (user) => {
  axios.post('api', {
    username: user
  })
  .then((res) => {
    this.setState({
      credit: res.credit,
      points: res.points
    })
    console.log(`this is user stats\ncredit:${res.credit}\npoints:${res.points} for the user: ${user}`)
  })
}


router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    UserData.findOne({                    
        username: req.body.username,                         
    }, 

    (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in saving user to mongodb: ' + err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            if(user.username === req.body.username) {
                console.log('fetching data for: ' + user.username);
                console.log(user);
                res.send(user);
            }
        }
    });

})
```

RESPONSE FROM POSTMAN:

```
{"_id":"5afd9bXXXXXXX664a5af","username":"check","credit":1,"points":0,"__v":0}
```

RESPONSE ON APP CONSOLE:

```
this is user stats credit:undefined points:undefined for the user: check
```

Comment: What do you see when you just log `res` from the post response handler?

Comment: @Dave Newton you fixed my problem thanks. the object is actually `res.data`

Comment: @obiwankenoobi Cool. #1 rule: always check your assumptions, especially when it's easy enough to do so :)

Comment: @obiwankenoobi debugging 101: *always* log stuff. especially before posting questions on stack overflow.

Comment: @Chris G well to be honest I do log everything. As you can see on the server. Any way, I'm sure I wont be the last one who tackle this issue so.. good the solution it's out there(:

Comment: @obiwankenoobi Not trying to be extra rude or anything but the solution is already in the axios documentation, which means is has no business being on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: hey man (: you absolutely right! This one is on me no doubt. Yet, I'm sure it didn't harm anyone that I posted it here. Or is it..?  Im just a noob trying to figure it out you know? Also if I'd thought its an axios issue believe me first thing I'd do is check the docs.. it's much quicker then post on SO. But, who knew? Thanks anyway(:

Answer (score 2):

to read data from the response I should have to use 'res.data.something' and not `res.something`